# boost::interprocess::map compiler error "cannot be overloaded"

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I am getting a compiler error trying to use boost::interprocess:map and I do not understand the error.

Declaring the map and its allocator

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;

struct Order {
    uint64_t id = 0;
    uint64_t val = 0;
};

typedef std::pair<const uint64_t, Order> ValueType;
typedef allocator<ValueType, 
                  managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> OrderMapAllocator;
typedef map<const uint64_t, 
            Order, 
            std::less<const uint64_t>, 
            OrderMapAllocator> OrderMap;
```

Example usage, the compiler error points out line 120 which is the first line of the function below:

```
OrderMap * _orders;

void addOrder(Order order) {
    if(_orders->find(order.id) != _orders->end()){
        /* stuff */
    } else {
        (*_orders)[order.id] = order;
    }
}
```

Note, I previously ran the code using std::map successfully, with the key non const instead of const.  I switched the key to const uint64_t because a type assertion in boost was failing.

Gets the compiler errors below which I cannot interpret

For conciseness, the first one ends:

```
boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::nonconst_value_type = std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>]’ cannot be overloaded
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert(const nonconst_value_type& x)
```

-

```
In file included from include/boost/interprocess/containers/map.hpp:23:0,
                 from src/app/SharedOrderBook.h:7,
                 from src/app/futures_feed.cpp:20:
include/boost/container/map.hpp: In instantiation of ‘class boost::container::map<const long unsigned int, Order, std::less<const long unsigned int>, boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> > >’:
src/app/SharedOrderBook.h:120:19:   required from here
include/boost/container/map.hpp:541:29: error: ‘std::pair<typename boost::container::container_detail::tree<Key, std::pair<const Key, T>, boost::container::container_detail::select1st<std::pair<const Key, T> >, Compare, Allocator, MapOptions>::iterator, bool> boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::insert(const nonconst_value_type&) [with Key = const long unsigned int; T = Order; Compare = std::less<const long unsigned int>; Allocator = boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >; MapOptions = boost::container::tree_opt<(boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>; typename boost::container::container_detail::tree<Key, std::pair<const Key, T>, boost::container::container_detail::select1st<std::pair<const Key, T> >, Compare, Allocator, MapOptions>::iterator = boost::container::container_detail::iterator_from_iiterator<boost::intrusive::tree_iterator<boost::intrusive::bhtraits<boost::container::container_detail::tree_node<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>, boost::intrusive::rbtree_node_traits<boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, true>, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)0u, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 3u>, false>, false>; boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::nonconst_value_type = std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>]’ cannot be overloaded
    std::pair<iterator,bool> insert(const nonconst_value_type& x)
                             ^~~~~~
include/boost/container/map.hpp:530:29: error: with ‘std::pair<typename boost::container::container_detail::tree<Key, std::pair<const Key, T>, boost::container::container_detail::select1st<std::pair<const Key, T> >, Compare, Allocator, MapOptions>::iterator, bool> boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::insert(const value_type&) [with Key = const long unsigned int; T = Order; Compare = std::less<const long unsigned int>; Allocator = boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >; MapOptions = boost::container::tree_opt<(boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>; typename boost::container::container_detail::tree<Key, std::pair<const Key, T>, boost::container::container_detail::select1st<std::pair<const Key, T> >, Compare, Allocator, MapOptions>::iterator = boost::container::container_detail::iterator_from_iiterator<boost::intrusive::tree_iterator<boost::intrusive::bhtraits<boost::container::container_detail::tree_node<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>, boost::intrusive::rbtree_node_traits<boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, true>, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)0u, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 3u>, false>, false>; boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::value_type = std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>]’
    std::pair<iterator,bool> insert(const value_type& x)
                             ^~~~~~
include/boost/container/map.hpp:574:29: error: ‘std::pair<typename boost::container::container_detail::tree<Key, std::pair<const Key, T>, boost::container::container_detail::select1st<std::pair<const Key, T> >, Compare, Allocator, MapOptions>::iterator, bool> boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::insert(boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::value_type&&) [with Key = const long unsigned int; T = Order; Compare = std::less<const long unsigned int>; Allocator = boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >; MapOptions = boost::container::tree_opt<(boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>; typename boost::container::container_detail::tree<Key, std::pair<const Key, T>, boost::container::container_detail::select1st<std::pair<const Key, T> >, Compare, Allocator, MapOptions>::iterator = boost::container::container_detail::iterator_from_iiterator<boost::intrusive::tree_iterator<boost::intrusive::bhtraits<boost::container::container_detail::tree_node<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>, boost::intrusive::rbtree_node_traits<boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, true>, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)0u, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 3u>, false>, false>; boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::value_type = std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>]’ cannot be overloaded
    std::pair<iterator,bool> insert(BOOST_RV_REF(value_type) x)
                             ^~~~~~
include/boost/container/map.hpp:552:29: error: with ‘std::pair<typename boost::container::container_detail::tree<Key, std::pair<const Key, T>, boost::container::container_detail::select1st<std::pair<const Key, T> >, Compare, Allocator, MapOptions>::iterator, bool> boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::insert(boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::nonconst_value_type&&) [with Key = const long unsigned int; T = Order; Compare = std::less<const long unsigned int>; Allocator = boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >; MapOptions = boost::container::tree_opt<(boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>; typename boost::container::container_detail::tree<Key, std::pair<const Key, T>, boost::container::container_detail::select1st<std::pair<const Key, T> >, Compare, Allocator, MapOptions>::iterator = boost::container::container_detail::iterator_from_iiterator<boost::intrusive::tree_iterator<boost::intrusive::bhtraits<boost::container::container_detail::tree_node<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>, boost::intrusive::rbtree_node_traits<boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, true>, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)0u, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 3u>, false>, false>; boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::nonconst_value_type = std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>]’
    std::pair<iterator,bool> insert(BOOST_RV_REF(nonconst_value_type) x)
                             ^~~~~~
include/boost/container/map.hpp:619:13: error: ‘boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::iterator boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::insert(boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::const_iterator, const nonconst_value_type&) [with Key = const long unsigned int; T = Order; Compare = std::less<const long unsigned int>; Allocator = boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >; MapOptions = boost::container::tree_opt<(boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>; boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::iterator = boost::container::container_detail::iterator_from_iiterator<boost::intrusive::tree_iterator<boost::intrusive::bhtraits<boost::container::container_detail::tree_node<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>, boost::intrusive::rbtree_node_traits<boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, true>, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)0u, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 3u>, false>, false>; boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::const_iterator = boost::container::container_detail::iterator_from_iiterator<boost::intrusive::tree_iterator<boost::intrusive::bhtraits<boost::container::container_detail::tree_node<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>, boost::intrusive::rbtree_node_traits<boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, true>, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)0u, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 3u>, false>, true>; boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::nonconst_value_type = std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>]’ cannot be overloaded
    iterator insert(const_iterator p, const nonconst_value_type& x)
             ^~~~~~
include/boost/container/map.hpp:586:13: error: with ‘boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::iterator boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::insert(boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::const_iterator, const value_type&) [with Key = const long unsigned int; T = Order; Compare = std::less<const long unsigned int>; Allocator = boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >; MapOptions = boost::container::tree_opt<(boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>; boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::iterator = boost::container::container_detail::iterator_from_iiterator<boost::intrusive::tree_iterator<boost::intrusive::bhtraits<boost::container::container_detail::tree_node<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>, boost::intrusive::rbtree_node_traits<boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, true>, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)0u, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 3u>, false>, false>; boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::const_iterator = boost::container::container_detail::iterator_from_iiterator<boost::intrusive::tree_iterator<boost::intrusive::bhtraits<boost::container::container_detail::tree_node<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>, boost::intrusive::rbtree_node_traits<boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, true>, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)0u, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 3u>, false>, true>; boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::value_type = std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>]’
    iterator insert(const_iterator p, const value_type& x)
             ^~~~~~
include/boost/container/map.hpp:628:13: error: ‘boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::iterator boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::insert(boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::const_iterator, boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::value_type&&) [with Key = const long unsigned int; T = Order; Compare = std::less<const long unsigned int>; Allocator = boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >; MapOptions = boost::container::tree_opt<(boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>; boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::iterator = boost::container::container_detail::iterator_from_iiterator<boost::intrusive::tree_iterator<boost::intrusive::bhtraits<boost::container::container_detail::tree_node<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>, boost::intrusive::rbtree_node_traits<boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, true>, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)0u, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 3u>, false>, false>; boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::const_iterator = boost::container::container_detail::iterator_from_iiterator<boost::intrusive::tree_iterator<boost::intrusive::bhtraits<boost::container::container_detail::tree_node<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>, boost::intrusive::rbtree_node_traits<boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, true>, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)0u, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 3u>, false>, true>; boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::value_type = std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>]’ cannot be overloaded
    iterator insert(const_iterator p, BOOST_RV_REF(value_type) x)
             ^~~~~~
include/boost/container/map.hpp:598:13: error: with ‘boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::iterator boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::insert(boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::const_iterator, boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::nonconst_value_type&&) [with Key = const long unsigned int; T = Order; Compare = std::less<const long unsigned int>; Allocator = boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >; MapOptions = boost::container::tree_opt<(boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>; boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::iterator = boost::container::container_detail::iterator_from_iiterator<boost::intrusive::tree_iterator<boost::intrusive::bhtraits<boost::container::container_detail::tree_node<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>, boost::intrusive::rbtree_node_traits<boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, true>, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)0u, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 3u>, false>, false>; boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::const_iterator = boost::container::container_detail::iterator_from_iiterator<boost::intrusive::tree_iterator<boost::intrusive::bhtraits<boost::container::container_detail::tree_node<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, (boost::container::tree_type_enum)0u, true>, boost::intrusive::rbtree_node_traits<boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>, true>, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)0u, boost::intrusive::dft_tag, 3u>, false>, true>; boost::container::map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator, Options>::nonconst_value_type = std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>]’
    iterator insert(const_iterator p, BOOST_RV_REF(nonconst_value_type) x)
             ^~~~~~
In file included from include/boost/interprocess/segment_manager.hpp:33:0,
                 from include/boost/interprocess/detail/managed_memory_impl.hpp:30,
                 from include/boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp:25,
                 from src/app/SharedOrderBook.h:6,
                 from src/app/futures_feed.cpp:20:
include/boost/interprocess/detail/named_proxy.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::CtorArgN<T, is_iterator, Args>::construct(void*, boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::false_, const boost::container::container_detail::index_tuple<IdxPack ...>&) [with int ...IdxPack = {0, 1}; T = boost::container::map<const long unsigned int, Order, std::less<const long unsigned int>, boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> > >; bool is_iterator = false; Args = {std::less<long unsigned int>, boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void, long int, long unsigned int, 0ul>, 0ul>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >&}; boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::false_ = boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::bool_<false>]’:
include/boost/interprocess/detail/named_proxy.hpp:71:10:   required from ‘void boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::CtorArgN<T, is_iterator, Args>::construct_n(void*, std::size_t, std::size_t&) [with T = boost::container::map<const long unsigned int, Order, std::less<const long unsigned int>, boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> > >; bool is_iterator = false; Args = {std::less<long unsigned int>, boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void, long int, long unsigned int, 0ul>, 0ul>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >&}; std::size_t = long unsigned int]’
src/app/futures_feed.cpp:170:1:   required from here
include/boost/interprocess/detail/named_proxy.hpp:83:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::container::map<const long unsigned int, Order, std::less<const long unsigned int>, boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> > >::map(std::less<long unsigned int>, boost::interprocess::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Order>, boost::interprocess::segment_manager<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family>, boost::interprocess::iset_index> >&)’
    {  ::new((void*)mem, boost_container_new_t())T(boost::forward<Args>(get<IdxPack>(args_))...); }
```

If I get rid of the const uint64_t and use uint64_t for the key, I get the error below:

```
include/boost/container/map.hpp:150:7: error: static assertion failed: (container_detail::is_same<std::pair<const Key, T>, typename Allocator::value_type>::value)
       BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((container_detail::is_same<std::pair<const Key, T>, typename Allocator::value_type>::value));
```

Comment: Remove the const from `map <const unit64_t`, but leave it in the allocator and ValueType definitions.

Comment: This worked, thank you